Pygame - Dibujar un rectangulo/cuadrado con bordes
Estoy haciendo un juego en pygame que consiste en ir recogiendo los bloques 10x10 que te aparecen en la pantalla en posiciones random. Estos los recoges simplemente pasandole por encima con tu bloque personal que se mueve con tu cursor. Quiero agregarles un borde interno de 1x1 a cada bloque para darle un aspecto mas cool pero no lo he podido lograr.. Este es el codigo, es un codigo bastante simple, los bloques los manejo bajo esta clase:
# Esta clase representa cada bloque.     
# Deriva de la clase "Sprite" en Pygame.
class Bloque(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
     
    # Constructor. Pasa el color del bloque, 
    # así como su posición x,y
    def __init__(self, color, largo, alto):
        # Llamada al constructor de la clase padre (Sprite) 
        super().__init__() 
 
        # Creamos una imagen del bloque y la rellenamos de color.        
        self.image = pygame.Surface([largo, alto])
        self.image.fill(color)

        # Extraemos el objeto rectángulo que posee las dimensiones de la imagen.
        # Estableciendo los valores rect.x e rect.y, actualizamos la posición de este objeto.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

Luego con este ciclo creo todo los bloques:
for i in range(10):
    # Esto representa un bloque
    bloque = Bloque(NEGRO, 10, 10)
 
    # Establecemos una ubicación aleatoria para el bloque.
    bloque.rect.x = random.randrange(LARGO_PANTALLA)
    bloque.rect.y = random.randrange(ALTO_PANTALLA)
     
    # Añadimos el bloque a la lista de objetos.
    listade_bloques.add(bloque)
    listade_todolos_sprites.add(bloque)

Con este codigo voy sacando de la lista a todos los bloques que mi bloque principal intercepta:
    #Observamos por si el bloque protagonista ha colisionado contra algo.
    lista_impactos_bloques = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(protagonista, listade_bloques, True)  
     
    # Comprobamos la lista de colisiones
    for bloque in lista_impactos_bloques:
        puntuacion += 1
        print( puntuacion )

Y al final del ciclo principal con este codigo dibujo todos los bloques que faltan por interceptar:
    # Limpiamos la pantalla
    pantalla.fill(BLANCO)
 
    # Dibujamos todos los sprites
    listade_todolos_sprites.draw(pantalla)

El codigo ya funciona bien, solo tengo que comenzar a darle estilo y no he logrado lo del borde..
Alguna pista o sugerencia de como podria lograrlo?

Si te refieres a agregar un borde de otro color al sprite, dado que este es rectangular, puedes usar pygame.draw.rect() para dibujar un rectángulo en su propia surface. Solo recuerda hacer uso del argumento width para establecer el ancho de la linea (1 en tu caso), algo como:
pygame.draw.rect(
    self.image,
    color_del_borde,
    self.rect,
    1
)

en el mismo iniclizador de tu clace Bloque.
Un ejemplo reproducible basado en tu código (simplificado, cada click del ratón hace aparecer un nuevo bloque):
import pygame


LARGO_PANTALLA = 600
ALTO_PANTALLA = 600
NEGRO = 0, 0, 0
BLANCO = 255, 255, 255
RED = 255, 0, 0


class Bloque(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
     
    def __init__(self, color, color_borde, largo, alto):
        super().__init__() 
        
        self.image = pygame.Surface([largo, alto])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    
        pygame.draw.rect(
            self.image,
            color_borde,
            self.rect,
            5  # Ancho del borde
        )
        
        
pygame.init()
pantalla = pygame.display.set_mode((LARGO_PANTALLA, ALTO_PANTALLA))
lista_de_todos_los_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        match event.type:
            case pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            case pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                bloque = Bloque(NEGRO, RED, 40, 40)
                bloque.rect.x = random.randrange(LARGO_PANTALLA - 40)
                bloque.rect.y = random.randrange(ALTO_PANTALLA - 40)
                lista_de_todos_los_sprites.add(bloque)
 
    pantalla.fill(BLANCO)
    lista_de_todos_los_sprites.draw(pantalla)
    pygame.display.update()
 
pygame.quit()

He aumentado el tamaño de los bloques a 40 y el ancho del borde a 5 para que se vea mejor en el ejemplo, simplemente adaptalo a tu caso.

Una observación (hecha en base al código que muestras, por lo que puede o no ser un problema dependiendo de tu código completo), en principio si haces:
# Establecemos una ubicación aleatoria para el bloque.
bloque.rect.x = random.randrange(LARGO_PANTALLA)
bloque.rect.y = random.randrange(ALTO_PANTALLA)

potencialmente generarás bloques parcial o totalmente fuera de la pantalla (superando límite derecho y/o inferior de la misma). Ten en cuenta que los valores x e y son los del vértice superior izquierdo del rectángulo, si los estableces con los valores del tamaño de la pantalla el vértice superior izquierdo del sprite estará posicionado en el vertice inferior derecho de la pantalla y nada de él se verá. Deberias hacer algo como:
bloque.rect.x = random.randrange(LARGO_PANTALLA - LARGO_DEL_BLOQUE)
bloque.rect.y = random.randrange(ALTO_PANTALLA - ALTO_DEL_BLOQUE)



Es básico, pero puedes jugar bastante con ello, por ejemplo, borde con esquinas redondeadas:
class Bloque(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, color, color_borde, largo, alto, ancho_borde, radio_borde):
        super().__init__() 

        image = pygame.Surface([largo, alto], pygame.SRCALPHA, 32)
        self.image = image.convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        
        pygame.draw.rect(
            self.image,
            color,
            (ancho_borde, ancho_borde, largo - ancho_borde * 2, alto - ancho_borde * 2)
        )

        pygame.draw.rect(
            self.image,
            color_borde,
            self.rect,
            ancho_borde,
            radio_borde
        )


